# How to change the connection string with sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a connection string in a ini file as following:

```
1 ...
2 ...
3 #someline:
n ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Database=grid;User ID=grid;Password=grid;"
```

And I would like to locate to the line n and replcate Data Source, Database, User Id and Password field. So how can I make it in sed?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do - what do you mean by "replicate Data Source, Database, User Id and Password"?

Comment: @David, replace the locahost, grid, grid, grid with the real Data Source, Database, User ID and Password

Comment: Is the line number known or is this the only line that contains "ConnectionString" (or some other text that makes it unique)?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/localhost/DataSource/' -e 's/grid/Database/' -e 's/grid/UserId/' -e 's/grid/Password'
```

This assumes that the fields are always in this order, and that the string 'grid' does not appear in either the text or any previously substitued fields.

Comment: The first "grid" should be "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk

```
$ awk -vds="Datasource" -vdb="dbname" -vuser="userid" -vpswd="pass" '/Connection/{$0="Data Source="ds";Database="db";User ID="userid";Password="pswd}1' file
```

Comment: It seems that awk will remove all the other lines in my file.

Comment: No, the code will not remove all other lines. have you tried running it ?